# How to recover data in ubuntu after changing operating system from windows 8 to ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, boot, 18.04, data-recovery

I changed my operating system from windows 8 to UBUNTU by using a usb stick but in the process i lost all of my data. is there any way to recover it? Please help me the data was very important.

Comment: "Please help me the data was very important." If that is true you install the OS the backup was made on and restore the backup. Otherwise I do not understand your idea of "important data".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on details how it was done. Most probably Windows files were overwriten by Linux files. In such case almost nothing can be recovered. If some remnants of Windows' files are still alive then you will need to read disk sector by sector and attempt to reconstruct those files from sectors as 'big puzzle picture consisting of very many pieces'. Usually it is unfeasible.

I would recommend to try some 'autorecovery' tools. Unfortunately I am unable to recommend something specific.